# Android List View Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception - No clues?

Tags: java, android, listview, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an app which loads a listview when opened, however I am getting an Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception, with no clues as to where the problem lies. It is trying to access index=-1 somewhere, but I have no idea where.

The app loads Homework information from a database, puts them into separate Homework objects in an ArrayList and loads it into the ListView from there. I really don't know where the exception is coming from, I have checked all my code. There is only 1 homework in the list, however the app refuses to open and force closes as soon as I try to open it. Here is the LogCat output

Thanks

LogCat output

```
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=29; index=-1
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.text.StaticLayout.calculateEllipsis(StaticLayout.java:738)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.text.StaticLayout.out(StaticLayout.java:702)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:410)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:140)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:5888)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5745)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6102)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:645)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:425)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1183)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1248)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-11 16:38:43.644: E/AndroidRuntime(7267):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Loading from DB

```
public ArrayList<HomeworkItem> getHomeworks() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_SUBJECT,
                KEY_DUE_DAY, KEY_DUE_MONTH, KEY_DUE_YEAR, KEY_NOTES,
                KEY_REMINDER_ONE, KEY_REMINDER_TWO };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        ArrayList<HomeworkItem> hwks = new ArrayList<HomeworkItem>();

        int id = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iTitle = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE);
        int iSub = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SUBJECT);
        int iDay = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DUE_DAY);
        int iMonth = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DUE_MONTH);
        int iYear = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DUE_YEAR);
        int iNotes = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NOTES);
        int iOne = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDER_ONE);
        int iTwo = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMINDER_TWO);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            HomeworkItem h = new HomeworkItem();
            h.id = c.getInt(id);
            h.title = c.getString(iTitle);
            h.subject = c.getString(iSub);
            h.day = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iDay));
            h.month = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iMonth));
            h.year = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iYear));
            h.notes = c.getString(iNotes);
            h.late = h.isLate();

            h.oneDayReminder = Boolean.parseBoolean(c.getString(iOne));
            h.twoDayReminder = Boolean.parseBoolean(c.getString(iTwo));
            hwks.add(h);
        }
        return hwks;
    }
```

ListView Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter { // adapter for list

        public MyAdapter(Context c) {

        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("hwk", hwks.size()+" is the size");
            return hwks.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("hwk", position+" being accessed");
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("hwk", position+" being accessed");
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v = convertView; // inflate the list
            TextView title, subject, dueDate, listLate;

            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
                Log.d("hwk", "v inflated");
            }
            title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listTitle); // get the id's
                                                                // of fields
            subject = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listSubject);
            dueDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listDueDate);
            listLate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listLate);
            Log.d("hwk", "got views");

            title.setText(hwks.get(position).title);
            subject.setText(hwks.get(position).subject);
            String date = hwks.get(position).day + "/"
                    + (hwks.get(position).month + 1) + "/"
                    + hwks.get(position).year;
            dueDate.setText(date);
            Log.d("hwk", "some text set");

            if (hwks.get(position).late) { // set if they are late or not
                if (hwks.get(position).isToday()) {
                    listLate.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 165, 0));
                    listLate.setText("Due Today!");
                } else {
                    listLate.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    listLate.setText("Late");
                }
            } else {
                listLate.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                listLate.setText("Ongoing");
            }
            Log.d("hwk", "returning v");
            return v;
        }

    }
```

EDIT: Also, the ListView works when I first add a Homework within the app, and it goes and refreshes the ListView and adds the Homework to it. I am totally reloading the main Activity when this happens, so it appears to be a problem opening it after the app has been closed once.

EDIT 2: I deleted the data from the app, added a new Homework and now I cannot recreate the problem.. What could have caused this?!

EDIT 3: PROBLEM DETECTED. It is to do with some of the text. I have worked out that when I set the 'title' to "Binomial Expansion" it recreated the error that I had before when the homework was also called "Binomial Expansion". Could it be to do with trying to put that String in the TextView and the text being too large?

I have extended the width of the TextView and it stopped the error. When I extended the text I got the issue again. It must be a problem with the text view overflowing. Are there any TextView properties I can set to stop this?

Comment: " loads Homework information from a database, puts them into separate Homework objects in an ArrayList and loads it into the ListView" -- Could you post those bits of code?

Comment: @WeloSefer Do you need more code or is what I have added okay?

Comment: @TomRichardson Is there any specific reason to use BaseAdapter? if not, please try ArrayAdapter that will be easy..

Comment: `getItem` is returning the position instead of an item. Also, I think you want to return null from `getView` if the position is out of bounds. That's probably your exception.

Comment: Read the f'ing LogCat guys. The issue is **not** with the position of the adapter being -1 (that is impossible unless the device has a broken Android framework on it), but is caused by `android.text.StaticLayout.calculateEllipsis(StaticLayout.java:738)` which for some reason attempted to perform an operation at position `-1` in the string (which was 29 chars long).

Comment: @JosephEarl Thank you, but what could have been causing this?! I never would have seen that, I still don't understand how it could have happened..

Comment: @JosephEarl - check my last edit, I think I found the issue but don't know what is causing it or how to fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is caused by setting `android:ellipsize="middle"` (or `start`) on a `TextView` that does not have `android:singleLine="true"` on.

For example, the following crashes on this error:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="middle"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahbla---go really long" />
```

But the following does not:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="middle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahbla---go really long" />
```

Reference: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33868

Note: `singleLine` is a deprecated attribute but still works on Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in the getView method , this method will be called whenever u scroll through your array so make sure u check if the view is not null before doing any logic there.

Comment: I put a check in the getView method surrounding all the logic, making sure that the position is not less than 0, and I still get the same error.

Comment: The position will **never** be -1.

Comment: try checking if the view is not null before doing any logic in the getView.

Answer (score 0):

Check your layouts and cursor column name array lengths in the CursorAdapter's [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29).  When the two array's length mismatch, it causes `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely related to text view ellipsize logic, It has nothing to do with adapter code.